# How can I aggregate multiple thread groups together?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'm running Jmeter to load test an API with 3 endpoints and for this reason, I need to use 3 thread groups to represent normal traffic of this API.  In addition, I have 3 more thread groups to represent peak traffic of the API.  So I have 6 thread groups, and I don't see a way to get the results I want without having 6.

Aggregate functions operate on everything within their scope.  As-is, each of the 6 thread groups are in the same scope.  I want to aggregate the peak thread groups separately from the other 3, so that I can see the average response time whilst the API is being pounded vs. when it is relatively calm.  I'd need a component that can hold the thread groups within it, so I can separate their scopes.  Is there a way to do this?

I can, of course, aggregate each thread group separately, but I would prefer to also be able to combine the aggregate details in the way I've described above.  Thank you.

I expected to be able to file thread groups inside of something - such as a loop controller or another thread group.  This is not allowed, however.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want with 3 [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) only.

The number of threads doesn't have to be static, you can set it to a [JMeter Variable or a JMeter Property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and amend this property in the script (like first 5 minutes of test the number of threads is 10, then it's 100 for another five minutes, then it's 10 again, etc.)

Alternatively you can consider going to a more advanced Thread Group like [Open Model Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-model-thread-group) or [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which give you maximum flexibility when it comes to JMeter workload model definition.

[image]